# SOLVED: NodeJS - multiple nested functions to return something.another.item

Tags: node.js

I wanted to do the following:

```
var gEnv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
var gDev = gEnv.getScreenDevices();
```

UPDATE: Here is the function now working:

```
const GraphicsEnvironment =
{
  getLocalGraphicsEnvironment: function ()
  {
    this.getScreenDevices = function ()
    {
      return someValue;
    }
  }
}
```

The error is that getScreenDevices is not a function.

Comment: Instead of `getScreenDevices: function()`, you probably meant to do `this.getScreenDevices = function()`

Comment: @DemiPixel: I modified as you said but still getting an error. I've updated the OP.

Comment: So that all works for me--the only weird thing now is that `this.getScreenDevices()` calls itself in an infinite loop. Additionally, `value` is undefined, not sure if you have that set somewhere else.

Comment: @DemiPixel - Got it! Yea, this of course will infinite loop as stated. I just need a return value. Fixed the OP for others example.